Best approach API calls
At this point I call an API with PowerBi. The total amount of records are more than 500.000.
So to speed up the progress I made an manual export of the site from beginning date -> yesterday.
The export is on our database and with PowerBi I have a table with this export and a table with an "live" API from today.
So far so good but in a few weeks the "live" API table will fill up again with a lot of data and it will be slow.
The solution I had in mind:
1: The "live" API table is only the data of this week and the other table is all the data before this week.
How can I make a table with all the data before this week without this table to call the API over and over again. So the "live" API calls for this week must push the data into the "historical" table.
If there is a better/other solution for this, what should that solution be?

It sounds like you are looking for Power BI's hybrid table feature.
Through partitioning and incremental refresh, the same table can have some partitions in import mode and some partitions in direct query mode. In your case, this translates to historical API calls (before this week) being stored in import mode and current API calls (this week) being available through directy query partitions. You can utilize Power BI's built in partition management to offset the rolling historical partitions from your current interval, and thus Power BI's normal partition retention and such should still work for you. You could even store older data in larger partitions if desired (ex: monthly) while still keeping just the more recent 'live' data in a weekly partition.
The hybrid table is still queried normally through Power BI as a single table which makes using it much easier.
